# How to convert a dataframe from long to wide, with values grouped by year in the index?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

The code below worked with the previous csv that I used, both csv's have the same amount of columns, and the columns have the same name.

Data for the csv that worked [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/daily-min-temperatures.csv)

Data for csv that didnt [here](https://github.com/the-datadudes/deepSoilTemperature/blob/master/carringtonairtemp.csv)

What does this error mean? Why am I getting this error?

```
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import Grouper
from matplotlib import pyplot

series = read_csv('carringtonairtemp.csv', header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)

groups = series.groupby(Grouper(freq='A'))
years = DataFrame()

for name, group in groups:
    years[name.year] = group.values

years = years.T

pyplot.matshow(years, interpolation=None, aspect='auto')
pyplot.show()
```

### Error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7173fcbe8c08> in <module>
      6 #     display(group.head())
      7 #     print(group.values[:10])
----> 8     years[name.year] = group.values

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3038         else:
   3039             # set column
-> 3040             self._set_item(key, value)
   3041 
   3042     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3114         """
   3115         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3116         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3117         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3118 

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3759 
   3760             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3761             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index)
   3762             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3763                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index)
    745     """
    746     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 747         raise ValueError(
    748             "Length of values "
    749             f"({len(data)}) "

ValueError: Length of values (365) does not match length of index (252)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The issue with iteratively creating the dataframe in the manner shown, is it requires the new column to match the length of the existing dataframe, `year`, index.
- In the smaller dataset, all the years are 365 days without missing days.
- The larger dataset has mixed length years of 365 and 366 days and there is missing data from 1990 and 2020, which is causing `ValueError: Length of values (365) does not match length of index (252)`.
- Following is a more succinct script, which achieves the desired dataframe shape, and plot.

  - This implementation doesn't have issues with the unequal data lengths.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# links to data
url1 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trenton3983/stack_overflow/master/data/so_data/2020-09-19%20%2063975678/daily-min-temperatures.csv'
url2 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trenton3983/stack_overflow/master/data/so_data/2020-09-19%20%2063975678/carringtonairtemp.csv'

# load the data into a DataFrame, not a Series
# parse the dates, and set them as the index
df1 = pd.read_csv(url1, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
df2 = pd.read_csv(url2, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])

# groupby year and aggregate Temp into a list
dfg1 = df1.groupby(df1.index.year).agg({'Temp': list})
dfg2 = df2.groupby(df2.index.year).agg({'Temp': list})

# create a wide format dataframe with all the temp data expanded
df1_wide = pd.DataFrame(dfg1.Temp.tolist(), index=dfg1.index)
df2_wide = pd.DataFrame(dfg2.Temp.tolist(), index=dfg2.index)

# plot
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 10))

ax1.matshow(df1_wide, interpolation=None, aspect='auto')
ax2.matshow(df2_wide, interpolation=None, aspect='auto')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the groups do not have the same numbers of rows. So, firstly you add a column in the empty dataframe with 252 values and now the size of dataframe is 252. Then you are trying to add a column with 365 values which are a different size than 252. That's why you are getting this error. The datframe that the code worked had the same amount of values (364) per year(group). But now you have:

```
1990-12-31    252
1991-12-31    365
1992-12-31    366
...
```

For example, let's say we have this DataFrame:

```
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

If we try to add a column with two values we will get this error:

```
df['B']=[1,2]

ValueError: Length of values does not match the length of the index
```

It is ok only if we add the same number of values:

```
df['B']=[1,2,3]
```